# GWT: Reload Web Server Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm just running the default Greeting application that gets created in Eclipse.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
    final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
    nameField.setText("GWT Userrrr");
    final Label errorLabel = new Label();

    // We can add style names to widgets
    sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");

    // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
    // Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element
    RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
    RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);
    RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);

    // ...
}
```

For some reson if I change something e.g. comment out the `add()` for the button, those changes are not reflected by the web site. Not even if I click on the "Reload web server" button in the Development Mode view. If I do that I just get:

```
May 31, 2015 6:30:22 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule shutdown
INFO: Shutting down module instance default
May 31, 2015 6:30:22 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
May 31, 2015 6:30:23 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
May 31, 2015 6:30:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
May 31, 2015 6:30:23 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
   Reload completed successfully
```

but the changes are not applied.

The only thing that helps is re-compiling the whole GWT Project which unfortunately takes forever and is as such not the way I wanna go.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you using SuperDevMode or "classic" DevMode? How are you launching (Super)DevMode?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.java` files in the `server` package need to be compiled to `.class` to be interpreted by the server.

This is done by the GWT compiler which sadly compiles all the other client-side classes to javascript.

To speed up the development you can reduce the amount of permutations that the compiler does by specifying the target browser in the `xxx.gwt.xml` file

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Technically it is also possible to use the java compiler on you server side classes to compile them.

Quoting http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html

> **Class files**
>
> The build script generated by the webAppCreator utility automatically
>   takes care of compiling your servlet classes and placing them in the
>   war/WEB-INF/classes folder. However, it is possible that your
>   resources may fall out of sync as you make changes to your server-side
>   code that don’t necessarily incur changes in your GWT client-side
>   code, and hence you may forget to run the compiler to generate the new
>   .class files for your servlet classes. In such cases, you could run
>   the build script over your application code once more to generate the
>   new .class files, but **a simple javac would also suffice and probably
>   take less time to compile**. If the RPC service method signatures have
>   changed, however, then you will need to re-compile your application
>   with the GWT compiler.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether you are mistaken regarding it being necessary in the past. Yet in my understanding, eclipse tracks whether you have made any changes to the code and if so, a new binary is created to reflect the new code changes, no matter how small.

Comment: Well, and that part appears not to work somehow. I was expecting to *not* see the button if I comment out the `add()` part but the changes are not getting updated for some reason.

Comment: Remember you will only not see the button when you remove the front end code. This backend code only speaks to the logic behind the control.

Comment: Okay but what can I do about it? I don't want to re-compile the GWT project as it takes forever to do that every time.

Comment: My advice would be to right click on only the file that has been changed, rebuild just that file and you won't have to rebuild any of your other subprojects/classes.

Comment: You can't just rebuild a single file afaik. But however, this *should* work. I'm looking for a solution to this problem and not a workaround.